# Black outline is showing around react-native-modal-datetime-picker when dark mode of device is enable in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using

```json
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.4.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.0.0",
```

In Android devices, when the dark mode of the device is enabled. It shows a black border around the time picker. Please help to fix this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nafXp.jpg)